# Graph a function with \frac

Tags: graphs, fractions, tikz-pic

I need to graph the function
f(s)=\frac{s^3+7s^2+9s-128}
{s^2+15s+24} ,where s greater than zero,
please help me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using the package `tikz`. The following code shows how you can draw (any) graph using this package.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [gray,dotted] (0,-6) grid (10,7) ;
  \draw[->,>=latex] (0,0) -- (10,0) node[below]{$s$} ;
  \draw[->,>=latex] (0,-6) -- (0,7) node[left]{$f(s)$} ;

  \draw [domain=0:10,samples=200] plot (\x,{(\x^3+7*(\x)^2+9*\x-128)/((\x)^2+15*\x+24}) ;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This graph is drawn in the domain [0,10] with 200 samples. This can be adjusted according to what domain you want use and how smooth you want the curve to be.

Comment: Thanks, it helps @G. de Man